# How to keep and share auth data between selenium grid nodes?

Tags: python, docker, selenium, access-token, selenium-grid

I'm using selenium grid in docker. I want to login to website that I want to **scrape** before run in parallel many tasks. In general I want do login then keep auth data and share between all my nodes. Is it possible or maybe there is some nicer way to do this?
Because when I run in parallel all task I have no auth data, and I need to login on each

My compose:

```yaml
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20210311
    container_name: selenium-hub
    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20210311
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: selenium-hub
      HUB_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 5
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find how to reuse session, but I found how to do it yourself.
First of all I do login and then save cookies

```
# login logic...
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

After that I can setup these cookies to all my nodes.

```py
# Before setup your cookies go to related doamin. Without this cookies will not be setup

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```